# How to figure out why systemd service failed with result 'exit-code'?

Tags: python, systemd, python-daemon

I've created a python script that collects info for a 5 minute period and then sends data to aws cloudwatch. The body of the script runs forever in a while True: block, and when I run it on its own using `python3 to_cloud.py`, it functions successfully.

I made a service for it as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service for sending script data to cloudwatch
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/scripts/to_cloud.py
WorkingDirectory= /home/ubuntu/scripts
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start the service, it runs for the duration of the internal loop that collects the info, but then the following happens:

```
● to_cloud.service - Service for sending script data to cloudwatch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/to_cloud.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-06-23 16:53:44 UTC; 5s ago
    Process: 191072 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/scripts/to_cloud.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 191072 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 23 16:52:43 ip-172-31-19-11 systemd[1]: Started Service for sending script data to cloudwatch.
Jun 23 16:53:44 ip-172-31-19-11 systemd[1]: to_cloud.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 23 16:53:44 ip-172-31-19-11 systemd[1]: to_cloud.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

There are no logs in the journalctl so I'm wondering how to figure out what's going wrong. Thanks!